# How can I take a panorama with my Nikon DSLR on a dull day?

Tags: nikon, panorama, nikon-d3300

I went out the other day with my Nikon D3300 and tried to do a panorama, the camera said it was unable to do a panorama because it wasn't light enough, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Just to confirm — you're trying to use the Easy Panorama "effect" mode, right?

Comment: yes, i was using easy panorama mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use the camera's automatic "Easy Panorama" mode. Take the series of pictures manually and use desktop-computer software to stitch them together. This is a little more work on your part, but will be more flexible and probably yield better results anyway.